# io_getevents returns a completion event twice

Tags: asynchronous, io, linux-kernel

I've got a largish application which uses Linux's asynch IO via io_submit() and io_getevents(). Occasionally, io_getevents seems to return one of the IOs twice. This shows up either as a doubled entry in the 'events' array of returned events, or as an entry which duplicates one that was returned by a previous call to io_getevents().

```
int io_getevents(aio_context_t ctx_id, long min_nr, long nr,
                        struct io_event *events, struct timespec *timeout);
```

- The iocbs are posted to io_submit() one at a time.
- I use the return value from io_getevents to limit access to 'events'. I.e.,

  ```
  struct io_event event[EVENT_COUNT];
  // .. skip a bit
  reaped = io_getevents(_m_aio_context, count, EVENT_COUNT, event, &timeout);
  if(reaped < 0) {
    if(errno == EINTR) {
      continue;
    }

    perror("reap error:");
    assert(0);
  }

  assert(reaped <= (int)EVENT_COUNT);
  for(i = 0; i < reaped; i++) {
    struct my_iocb *my_iocb = (struct my_iocb *)event[i].obj;
    ...
    // The symptom is that my_iocb is the same pointer as event[i-1].obj,
    // or that my_iocb was recently returned by a previous call to
    // io_getevents() and was not re-submitted since then.
    ...
  ```

I'm afraid there is no realistic way to paste the rest of the relevant source here. However, I have added quite a bit of instrumentation to check that the same IOCB is never given to io_submit() twice, and to check for error returns from io_submit(). In my last instance of  the bug, none of the quarter billion calls to io_submit() since application start returned errors.

I'm posting this question to check if A) anybody has seen this before or B) this behavior is somehow expected.

If it is expected, what is a typical way of working around it? My application is in trouble because it frees the iocb at this point, and the obviously the second pointer to the same iocb causes a double-free/corruption etc.

Thanks!

Alex

Answer (score 1):

In io_submit you should set the aio_data field of struct iocb to the value of your context structure.

while processing completion event you should use event[i].data to look up the context pointer; don't use event[i].obj for that!

Also i have written a test that checks if notification is received twice: it checks this by setting a magic value in the request and the notification checks and resets this magic value; this test worked fine.

To compile it
    gcc -std=c++0x -g aio.cpp -lstdc++ -lpthread -o aio

The test:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* for perror() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* for syscall() */
#include <sys/syscall.h>    /* for __NR_* definitions */
#include <linux/aio_abi.h>  /* for AIO types and constants */
#include <fcntl.h>      /* O_RDWR */
#include <string.h>     /* memset() */
#include <inttypes.h>   /* uint64_t */

#include <atomic>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_EVENTS 1000

#define BLOCK_SIZE 4096
#define FILE_SIZE (BLOCK_SIZE * 10000)

#define MAGIC_VALUE 0xff0001DDEEFFAABB
#define MAGIC_SIZE  8

std::atomic<uint64_t> request_cnt;

int fd;
aio_context_t ctx;


#if 1

// no header on my system that has these - says that libaio does it;

inline int io_setup(unsigned nr, aio_context_t *ctxp)
{
    return syscall(__NR_io_setup, nr, ctxp);
}

inline int io_destroy(aio_context_t ctx) 
{
    return syscall(__NR_io_destroy, ctx);
}

inline int io_submit(aio_context_t ctx, long nr,  struct iocb **iocbpp) 
{
    return syscall(__NR_io_submit, ctx, nr, iocbpp);
}

inline int io_getevents(aio_context_t ctx, long min_nr, long max_nr,
        struct io_event *events, struct timespec *timeout)
{
    return syscall(__NR_io_getevents, ctx, min_nr, max_nr, events, timeout);
}

#endif





void *notification_th(void *)
{
    struct io_event events[MAX_EVENTS];
    int ret, i;

    while(true)
    {

        /* get the reply */
        ret = io_getevents(ctx, 1, MAX_EVENTS, events, NULL);
        for(i=0; i < ret; i++)
        {
            char *data = (char *) events[i].data;

            if (* ((uint64_t *) (data + BLOCK_SIZE)) != MAGIC_VALUE)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "notification received twice\n");
            }
            * ((uint64_t *) (data + BLOCK_SIZE)) = 0;

            //fprintf(stderr,"notify %p\n",data);

            delete [] data;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

void *sender_th(void *)
{
    char *data ;
    struct iocb cb;
    struct iocb *cbs[1];
    int ret;
    uint64_t cnt;


    while( true )
    {
        cnt = request_cnt.fetch_add( 1 );


        data = new char [ BLOCK_SIZE + MAGIC_SIZE ];
        memset( data, (char) cnt , BLOCK_SIZE );

        * ((uint64_t *) (data + BLOCK_SIZE)) = MAGIC_VALUE;

        /* setup I/O control block */
        memset(&cb, 0, sizeof(cb));
        cb.aio_fildes = fd;
        cb.aio_lio_opcode = IOCB_CMD_PWRITE;

        /* command-specific options */
        cb.aio_buf = (uint64_t)data;
        cb.aio_offset = (BLOCK_SIZE * cnt ) % FILE_SIZE;
        cb.aio_nbytes = BLOCK_SIZE;
        cb.aio_data = (uint64_t) data;

        cbs[0] = &cb;

        //fprintf(stderr,"submit %lu %p\n",cnt,data);

        ret = io_submit(ctx, 1, cbs);
        if (ret != 1) {
             if (ret < 0) {
            //fprintf(stderr,"error %lu %p\n",cnt,data);
            perror("io_submit error");
             } else
            fprintf(stderr, "could not sumbit IOs");
            return  NULL;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}   

int main()
{
    int i;
    int ret;

    request_cnt = 0;

    fd = open("/tmp/testfile", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open error");
        return -1;
    }

    ctx = 0;

    ret = io_setup(10000, &ctx);
    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("io_setup error");
        return -1;
    }

    pthread_t th;
    pthread_create(&th,NULL,notification_th,NULL);

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        pthread_t th;
        pthread_create(&th,NULL,notification_th,NULL);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        pthread_t th;
        pthread_create(&th,NULL,sender_th,NULL);
    }


    void *value;
    pthread_join(th,&value);


    ret = io_destroy(ctx);
    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("io_destroy error");
        return -1;
    }


return 0;
}
```